# magento cron job is working or not? how to check?

Tags: cron, catalog-price-rules

we are using magento 1.9.0 version.

we applied catalog price rules for our products to give discounts for products.

but these special prices will disappear after some time.

is  it problem with magento cron job. if so how to check whether cron job is working or not in site.

if not working means, what's the solution.

let me know if you have any queries.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running cronjob.php or.sh... in both cases you could edit the files and let it send a email to you when it runs.

A second solution would be to try out this amazing extension giving you the best insight in the health, quality and possible issues with you cronjobs.

This extensions shows you the schedule of you cronjob and gives you insight if it runs and how long tasks take and which tasks have run.

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: cron.sh and cron.php both file are in root of the site.

cron.sh = http://pastebin.com/4mgkdZrf

cron.php = http://pastebin.com/dzvSFLzy

please tell me what lines need to be edit.....

Comment: In the php file you can just paste a line like this:  mail('<your email>,'cronjob just ran','The cronjob succesfully run');

Comment: i installed this extension : https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

its displaying cron job is not working.

so i want to use this : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

they mentioned like this for unix based systems : http://pastebin.com/WXeGVPxJ

i am new to these ssh commands.

please inform me what commands i have to run in above link to install cron job succesfully

Answer (score 1):

Have an observer that will insert a row into a table of your DB that shows the exact time that a certain cron is scheduled to run, then when that cron is ran have that same observer update that row to show that it is executed, then when it is complete once again update the row.  if there is an error, log that error within your DB.

This will allow you to easily access and view and past - present - and future cron tasks in one place!  Email is too distributed.

Comment: thanks for reply, i am new to this magento, can you explain me in detail or can you give any link that will explain in  detail....